# Unitary Representations of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: representation-theory

We suppose $\pi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}^\times$ is given by

$$\pi_t = e^{2 \pi i \cdot t} \hspace{1cm} t \in \mathbb{R}$$

is a representation of $\mathbb{R}$. I seek to show that $\pi$ is a unitary representation with respect to the usual inner product on $\mathbb{C}$ given by

$$\langle z_1, z_2 \rangle = z_1 \cdot \overline{z_2}$$

So we check to see that $\langle z_1, z_2 \rangle = \langle \pi_t(z_1), \pi_t(z_2) \rangle$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.

Well obviously, like we said $\langle z_1, z_2 \rangle = z_1 \cdot \overline{z_2}$. So now we need only determine $\langle \pi_t(z_1), \pi_t(z_2) \rangle$. Well

$$\langle \pi_t(z_1), \pi_t(z_2) \rangle = e^{2 \pi i t \cdot t} z_1 \cdot \overline{e^{2\pi i \cdot t} z_2}$$

But isn't it true that $e^{2 \pi i t \cdot t} z_1 \cdot \overline{e^{2\pi i \cdot t} z_2} = z_1 \cdot \overline{z_2}$ if and only if $t \in \mathbb{Z}$? In other words, doesn't $t$ need to make $\pi_t$ a multiple of $2 \pi$ in order for the inner products to be equal? And since $\mathbb{R} \neq \mathbb{N}$, then there are elements of $\mathbb{R}$ which fail to make $\pi$ unitary.

Am I misinterpreting the approach this problem?

---

**Solution(?)**

$$e^{2 \pi i \cdot t} z_1 \cdot e^{-2 \pi i \cdot t} \overline{z_2} = \big( e^{(2\pi - 2\pi)it}\big) \, z_1 \cdot \overline{z_2} = z_1 \cdot \overline{z_2}$$

Comment: Why do you think $t$ needs to be in $\mathbb{Z}$ for that?  Maybe you are missing that the conjugate will turn the second $e^{2\pi it}$ into $e^{-2\pi it}$...

Comment: @EricWofsey I thought about it some more and I'm just now recalling that $e^{2\pi i t} = (e^{2\pi i})^t = (\cos(2 \pi) + i \sin(2\pi))^t = 1^t = 1$. Either way, conjugate or no conjugate, $\pi_t$ boils down to $1$.

Comment: @cheesefoot $e^{2\pi it} = (e^{2\pi i})^t$ only holds in certain cases (e.g. $t\in \mathbb{Z}$, otherwise depending on branches)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Exactly. That's my problem. That's what I'm asking about. If it doesn't hold for all reals, then $e^{2\pi i \cdot t}$ can't always be $1$, but then how can $\pi$ be unitary?

Comment: Read Eric's comment again, then.  You neither need nor want $\pi_t=1$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Oh so he's saying $e^{2 \pi i \cdot t} z_1 \cdot e^{- 2\pi i t} \overline{z_2} = \big( e^{(2\pi - 2\pi) i \cdot t}\big)  z_1 \cdot \overline{z_2} = z_1 \cdot \overline{z_2}$?